# Can we use of Nested where clause in sails js Collection

Tags: sails.js, sails-mongo

I am trying below queries to get the output which has start_date greater than current date.

These in structure of my collection:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aeac6cd1b7e6f252832ca0e"), 
    "recruiter_id" : null, 
    "university_id" : null, 
    "type" : "quiz", 
    "name" : "Enter scheduled quiz without end date", 
    "description" : "Even after detailed market research, some products just don't work in the market. Here's a case study from the Coca-Cola range. ", 
    "quizpoll_image" : "story_7.jpeg", 
    "status" : "1", 
    "quizpoll_type" : "scheduled", 
    "duration" : {
        "duration_type" : "Question wise", 
        "total_duration" : "1000"
    }, 
    "questions" : [
        {
            "question_id" : "5aeaa4021b7e6f00dc80c5c6"
        }, 
        {
            "question_id" : "5aeaa59d1b7e6f00dc80c5d2"
        }
    ], 
    "date_type" : {
        "start_date" : ISODate("2018-05-01T00:00:00.000+0000")
    }, 
    "created_at" : ISODate("2018-05-01T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2018-04-26T07:58:17.795+0000")
}
```

This the query I am trying :

```
var isoCurrentDate = current_date.toISOString();
        var quizScheduledData = await QuizListingCollection.find({
                where: ({
                    'type':'quiz',
                    'status':'1',
                    'quizpoll_type':'scheduled',
                    'date_type' :{
                            'start_date':{
                                '>': isoCurrentDate       
                            }
                        }
                    })
            });
```

This is the error I get when I hit this api in postman

```
{
    "cause": {
        "name": "UsageError",
        "code": "E_INVALID_CRITERIA",
        "details": "Could not use the provided `where` clause.  Could not filter by `date_type`: Unrecognized modifier (`start_date`) within provided constraint for `date_type`."
    },
    "isOperational": true,
    "code": "E_INVALID_CRITERIA",
    "details": "Could not use the provided `where` clause.  Could not filter by `date_type`: Unrecognized modifier (`start_date`) within provided constraint for `date_type`."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
where: {
        'type':'quiz',
        'status':'1',
        'quizpoll_type':'scheduled',
        'date_type.start_date': {
                '>' : isoCurrentDate 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `.` operator I tried this earlier it also fails to work.

Comment: I tried its not working though I am trying some other work-around